# Compare two Maps<String, List<String>> and get map key + map value as differences

Tags: java, collections

I have two Maps of type Map<String, List>, which I need to compare and when I get different values in the List, I need to retrieve those values with their corresponding Map key.The two maps look like this:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new TreeMap<>();
    Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new TreeMap<>();

    map1.put("Column1", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "four"));
    map1.put("Column2", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "four"));

    map2.put("Column1", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
    map2.put("Column2", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

After comparison, the result should be something like: "Different value at Key 1, element 3. Different value at Key 2, element 3". How could I iterate through the two given maps so I can get to the corresponding index of different element? I tried creating a flatMap out of each Map, but then I lose the keySet for the different element between the lists.

Comment: Do your maps have always the same size and contain the same keyset and differ only in values?

Comment: No, they will differ in size, keysets and also the list of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.  Without knowing the nature of your data, it was important to at least mention border cases.

- First, your example implies you are doing positional differences.  So `"one","two"` would be different than `"two","one"` and thus flagged as `elements 0, 1` are different.
- The maps may have different keys.  This means that for any given key, the contents of the map missing the key are all different.
- The lists of corresponding keys may have different numbers of elements.  The first few could be the same. Any element missing and not just different is flagged.

Here is the data

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new TreeMap<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new TreeMap<>();

map1.put("Column1", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "four"));
map1.put("Column2", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "four"));
map1.put("Column3", Arrays.asList("three", "two"));
map1.put("Column4", Arrays.asList("one","two","three"));
map1.put("Column6", Arrays.asList("nine","ten"));
    
map2.put("Column1", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
map2.put("Column2", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three","four","five"));
map2.put("Column3", Arrays.asList("three"));
map2.put("Column4", Arrays.asList("one", "two","three"));
map2.put("Column5", Arrays.asList("one", "two","three"));
```

Now create a set that contains all the keys of both maps. Sorting isn't required but makes it easier to compare to the data.

```
SortedSet<String>keySet = new TreeSet<>(map1.keySet()); 
keySet.addAll(map2.keySet());
```

- First, guard against nulls lists (for missing keys) by creating an empty list.
- Iterate over the lists, comparing values for the same key.
- if different, call helper method to obtain the indices where different
- display the information.

```
for (String key : keySet) {
    List<String>list1 = Objects.requireNonNullElse(map1.get(key), List.of());
    List<String>list2 = Objects.requireNonNullElse(map2.get(key), List.of());
    if (!list1.equals(list2)) {
        int[] diffs = getIndices(list1,list2);
        System.out.printf("Maps different at key '%s', element(s) %s", key, diffs[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < diffs.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf(", %s", diffs[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The above prints

```
Maps different at key 'Column1', element(s) 2
Maps different at key 'Column2', element(s) 2, 3, 4
Maps different at key 'Column3', element(s) 1
Maps different at key 'Column5', element(s) 0, 1, 2
Maps different at key 'Column6', element(s) 0, 1
```

Helper method.

- compute the min and max sizes for the lists
- stream the indices for the max list.
- if the index is within both lists bounds, do the comparison
- if the comparison is different, pass the index.
- if the index is beyond the bounds, pass it since it flags missing list items.
- then return the array of indices

```
public static <T> int[] getIndices(List<T> list1,
        List<T> list2) {
    int min = Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size());
    int max = Math.max(list1.size(), list2.size());
    int[] diffs = IntStream.range(0, max)
            .filter(i -> i >= min || !list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(i)))
            .toArray();
    return diffs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution returns what I need. I will invest some time in understanding it as it exceeds my Java level. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do the comparison (e.g. the order matter? if not, use `Set` instead `List`).

One way to compare *"the corresponding index of different element"* is:

```
Map<String, List<String>> diffs = Streams.concat(xs.keySet().stream(), ys.keySet().stream())
        .distinct()
        .collect(toMap(k -> k, k -> {
            List<String> x = xs.getOrDefault(k, emptyList());
            List<String> y = ys.getOrDefault(k, emptyList());
            return IntStream.range(0, Math.max(x.size(), y.size()))
                    .mapToObj(i -> i < x.size() ? (i < y.size() ? (x.get(i).equals(y.get(i)) ? "=": "<>"): "X") : "Y")
                    .collect(toList());
        }));
```

where you get `=` if the elements at index `i` are equals, `<>` if are different or `X` or `Y` if that index exists only on one set.

For example:

```
xs.put("Column1", Arrays.asList("one", "xxx", "four"));
xs.put("Column2", Arrays.asList("one", "two"));
xs.put("Column3", Arrays.asList("cat"));

ys.put("Column1", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "four"));
ys.put("Column2", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
ys.put("Column4", Arrays.asList("apple"));
```

with output

```
{ Column1=[=, <>, =]
, Column2=[=, =, Y]
, Column3=[X]
, Column4=[Y]
}
```